# How can I collect the contents of cells from all prior revisions of a Google Sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-docs

I have a Google Sheet that tracks the number of pyjamas supplied and demanded on eBay at various price points. For example:

```
 At Price    There were so many listings    and so many bids
 $90         20                             25
 $100*        15                             17
```

*extra cozy pyjamas

Every day I updated these data. This involved writing over revised data. Fortunately, Google Sheets saved a decent quantity of the document's revision history. I want to recover those data, ideally panel-wise by time, e.g.:

```
On New Year's Eve
data

The next day
too drunk to input data
```

How do I extract the data from the latest revision on each day (feel free to define days liberally, albeit consistently)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [documents list API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/) to access all existing revisions for a given document, and then iterate through all of them, taking from them at intervals of 24 hrs (which you can check with the `updated` attribute existing on each recision entry). Then you can download the document of each revision taken.

Structurally, it would be a HTTP `GET` request for the revisions of a given document (something like `https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/resource_id/revisions`) and then iterate through those, and then just `GET` the ones that fit your criteria (of being spaces 24 hours apart).